# Результатом вычисления фрагмента не является функция. Вызов метода класса из переменной структуры

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонный класс для парсинга команд. Принцип такой: заполняется массив CmdList который содержит имя команды и указатель на метод в унаследованном классе от данного, сравниваем полученную команду с массивом и вызываем необходимый метод.

Вопрос такой: как правильно вызвать метод из этой структуры? Данный код вызывает ошибку компиляции.

> Ошибка C2064    результатом вычисления фрагмента не является функция, принимающая 1 аргументов

```
#ifndef _CONSOLECMDS_H
#define _CONSOLECMDS_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class ConsoleCmds
{
    protected:
        struct CmdList_t
        {
            std::string cmd = "";
            errno_t (T::*function)(std::vector<std::string>) = NULL;
        };

    private:
        std::vector<CmdList_t> CmdList;

    protected:
        errno_t CMD_ERROR = -1;

        ConsoleCmds() {}

        ~ConsoleCmds() {}

        void InitCmdList(std::vector<CmdList_t> list)
        {
            CmdList = list;
        }

        errno_t ParseCmd(std::vector<std::string> cmdArr)
        {
            errno_t err = CMD_ERROR;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < CmdList.size(); ++i)
            {
                if (CmdList[i].cmd == cmdArr[0])
                {
                    cmdArr.erase(cmdArr.begin());
                    err = CmdList[i].function(cmdArr);  //??????????
                    return (err);
                }
            }

            return (err);
        }
};

#endif //_CONSOLECMDS_H
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно чего Вы хотите добиться, напишите, как Вы планируете использовать этот шаблонный класс

Comment: `T object{}; (object.*(CmdList[i].function))(cmdArr);`

Comment: Так а для какого объекта вы собрались вызывать метод? Где вы возьмете объект? Без объекта типа `T` такой метод вызвать невозможно. И что такое "указатель на метод в наследуемом классе"? От чего наследуется `T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет об указателях на методы класса, унаследованного от вашего `ConsoleCmds`, то

1. Никакая шаблонность здесь не нужна, т.е. просто убираем `template<class T>`
2. Указатели объявляются как

   ```
   errno_t (ConsoleCmds::*function)(std::vector<std::string>)
   ```

   (непонятно только, почему вы во всем вашем коде передаете векторы по значению)

   Для упрощения приведения типа в пункте 4 лучше сначала создать псевдоним для этого типа

   ```
   using Cmd = errno_t (ConsoleCmds::*)(std::vector<std::string>);
   Cmd function;
   ```
3. Вызов делается как

   ```
   err = (this->*CmdList[i].function)(cmdArr);
   ```
4. При изначальном заполнении массива `std::vector<CmdList_t>` указателями на методы класса-наследника вам придется вручную приводить их к требуемому типу через `static_cast`. Вот тут-то как раз можно было бы локально применить шаблоны, чтобы не делать этот `static_cast` много раз подряд.

Comment: Точно, совсем забыл про приведение типов. Совсем недавно начал писать в стиле ООП. Насчёт векторов. Тогда как правильно их передавать в другие функции(методы)? Я использую `std::vector<std::string>` аля как в чистом Си `char** argv`, только аргументы берутся не из параметров командной строки, а из `std::in`. Вот [репозиторий](https://github.com/MrSago/Client-Server/tree/master/Client-Server/Client) где я этот класс использую.